# Web parts for GWT

Tags: gwt, web-parts

Does anyone know of a sample GWT code or third party package for making web parts that allow user to customize web site layout like it's done in iGoogle ?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing a few weeks ago. gwt-dnd is good but I found the motherload with **DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers**.

This is what you want?:

http://gwtquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/droppable/demo/GwtPortletSample/GwtPortletSample.html

Check out the project at:

http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers

It supports maven and GWT 2.2!

Answer (score 1):

Look at gwt-dnd, which has great support for dragging & dropping GWT widgets.  You'll have to save the position of the widgets if you want them to stay in the same place, but that's all!

http://allen-sauer.com/com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.demo.DragDropDemo/DragDropDemo.html#InsertPanelExample - drag the green boxes around.